# Rounding up decimal to the nearest multiple of 10 with php

Tags: php, decimal

Suppose I have the number "13.57916667" in a variable $hours. This is a calculated hours combining minutes and seconds to hours.

I want the decimals to round up. For example, I want $hours to become 13.6. I can't seem to find any solution anywhere, even on stackoverflow. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this little snippet should do it:

```
echo round(13.579, 1);
```

If you're looking for a `ceil()` with precision:

```
function ceil_with_precision($value, $precision = 0) {
    return ceil($value * pow(10, $precision)) / pow(10, $precision);
}
```

For a fixed precision of 1 decimal, that would become:

```
ceil($value * 10 ) / 10;
```

Comment: I understand that he wants the decimals ever rounded up. With this `round(13.02, 1);` you'll get `13` instead `13.1`.

Comment: This works great!

I modified another code I come across based on the one you provided, What's the difference between:

`return (ceil (pow (10, $precision) * $value) + ceil(pow (10, $precision) * $value - ceil (pow (10, $precision) * $value)))/pow (10, $precision);`

AND

`return ceil($value * pow(10, $precision)) / pow(10, $precision);`

Both return the same, is one more accurate than the other?

Comment: @cssExp I just see more code is all :) I don't see how the other is more accurate so I'd go with less code :)

Comment: I guess that's that! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$result = round($hours, 1);

See [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$roundednumber= round($number / 10, 0) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hours = (float) "13.57916667";
$hours = ceil($hours * 10) / 10;
```