# How do you round up the second decimal point to the nearest value that is divisible by 10 in C#

Tags: c#

I did all the due diligence I could and I found some answers in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232256/round-up-to-second-decimal-place-in-python), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030190/rounding-to-the-second-decimal-spot), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950300/rounding-up-decimal-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-10-with-php) and [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306238/is-there-a-condition-where-the-math-ceil-function-in-javascript-doesnt-remove-d/63306387#63306387) that didn't quite solve my problem...

In `C#` I am trying to round **up** the value of the 2nd decimal point to the nearest value that is divisible by 10. 
I have a **double** value `z` = 14.066666 
I need to turn `z` into 14.10

This is what I've *done* so far:

```
var result1 = Math.Ceiling(z);             // 15      (want 14.10)
var result2 = Math.Round(z,2);             // 14.7    (want 14.10)
var result3 = Math.Round(z,5);             // 14.0667 (want 14.10)
var result4 = Math.Ceiling(z*100)/100.0;   // 14.07   (want 14.10)
var result5 = Math.Ceiling(z*10)/10        // 14.1    (want 14.10)
```

Grateful for your consideration and thankful for any help that comes my way.

Comment: Would you want 14.01 to also round up to 14.1?

Comment: The last one there - result5 is actually the correct answer. The trailing zero is not really a part of the number. It is a part of string representation of a number.

Comment: 14.1 isn't divisible by 10. It's divisible by 0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

14.1 actually is equal to 14.10. The difference is in representation, not in value. To write this value with additional zero you have to specify proper formatting:

```
    double z = 14.066666;
    var result5 = Math.Ceiling(z*10)/10;
    Console.WriteLine("{0:N2}", result5);
```